# How to fetch the build parameters of a job that is in running state?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I want to fetch the build parameters from the latest build of a job, even if the latest build is still building.

def buildParameter = currentJob.getAction(ParametersAction.class)
paramValue = buildParameter.getParameter("modificationDate").getValue()
println(paramValue)

Answer (score 1):

```
def build = Jenkins.get().getItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob).find {it.displayName == 'YOUR_JOB_NAME_HERE'}?.getLastBuild()
build.actions.find{ it instanceof ParametersAction }?.parameters.each {echo "${it.name}=${it.value}"}
```